# Need help to get my Listbox.SeletectedIndex to work properly

Tags: c#, listbox

I need help to get my listbox.selecteditem to work.
This is my pseudo code.

```
public Form1()
{
    if (x == 1)
    {
        if (this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex != 5 ||
            this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ListBox1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseControlHandler(ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick); 
        } 
    }
    else 
    {
        //Do something else.
    }              
}

private void ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int index = this.ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Now I have gotten the condition to check when x is not 1; the double click does not work, which is what I wanted.
When x is 1; I have 10 items added to the listbox. I don't want the user to see the "Hello World!" message when the user clicks on the item with index =5.
I can't get this to work. Even when the user clicks on item with index = 5; the message still pops up. I tried debugging but the main pop up screen does not open during debugging. All I could see is selectedindex = -1. The real code is huge.

Is this the right approach to do this? Thanks.

Comment: The only issue you have is that you don't want the message to show when the user doubleclicks item with index=5?

Comment: Yes. And I think -1 is when nothing is clicked. Right now it works when I click on any item with every single index. I don't want it to work with item index 5.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. This is a pseudo code but pretty much represent the idea of what I'm trying to do. Thank you so much for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are using `||` (OR) when you should use `&&` (AND).
Let's break it down: when `index = 5`, you don't want anything to happen. But when `index = 5`, then `index != -1` is True and so the double click code is still triggered because `False OR True = True`. In addition, when `x != 1`, you need to unsubscribe from the event (or set it to null). If not, once it's set, it would be triggered if there is a double click event.

This is the code you want:

```cs
public Form1()
{
    if (x == 1 && this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex != 5 && this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
       ListBox1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseControlHandler(ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick);
    else 
    {
        ListBox1.MouseDoubleClick = null;
    }              
}

private void ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int index = this.ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try it out tomorrow and get back to you. My real code is not just 5 but like 20 other different indexes. Thank you for giving me a lead. I have been confused.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it today. It made a difference. Now my issue is that the ListBox1.SelectedIndex is always -1. It never changed even when I selected other items. I been reading on other property and method. Maybe ClearSelected could help me?

Comment: We will have to see the full code to know why. When you select an item, the selected index should change, unless you are somehow affecting that event

Comment: I figured it out. In short, the logic if statement to check for the index should be build inside the ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick method. Then the public Form1() should have just event itself without any condition. :D    Thank you man.